File.getCanonicalPath() returns inconsistent letter casing in path
In Open Data Kit's Android application ODK Collect, I am experiencing an issue with the File.getCanonicalPath() method, which sometimes returns paths with incorrect letter casing for the /Android/data/ path segment (Android should be capitalized, and data should be lowercase). For example, it returns:
/storage/emulated/0/android/data/... or /storage/emulated/0/android/Data/...
instead of
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/...
When I noticed the problem, I started logging these cases using Firebase Analytics, and I am certain that the original paths are correct: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/.... However, after calling File.getCanonicalPath(), the results may be as described above. I have received thousands of reports from Firebase, so I am unable to review them all to ensure that only the /Android/data/ path segment is affected by these changes, but from the reports I have managed to review, it seems that this is the only part of the path in question.
The method where I call File.getCanonicalPath() and log these unusual cases looks like this (link to the code on GitHub):
    fun getAbsoluteFilePath(dirPath: String, filePath: String): String {
        val absoluteFilePath =
            if (filePath.startsWith(dirPath)) filePath else dirPath + File.separator + filePath

        val canonicalAbsoluteFilePath = File(absoluteFilePath).canonicalPath
        val canonicalDirPath = File(dirPath).canonicalPath
        if (!canonicalAbsoluteFilePath.startsWith(canonicalDirPath)) {
            Timber.e(
                "Attempt to access file outside of Collect directory:\n" +
                    "dirPath: $dirPath\n" +
                    "filePath: $filePath\n" +
                    "absoluteFilePath: $absoluteFilePath\n" +
                    "canonicalAbsoluteFilePath: $canonicalAbsoluteFilePath\n" +
                    "canonicalDirPath: $canonicalDirPath"
            )
        }
        return absoluteFilePath
    }

My next step is to determine whether the issue is limited to the /Android/data/ part of the path, as mentioned above, or if other parts of the path might also be affected. To address this, I’ve written a method that sanitizes this part of the path:
    fun File.sanitizedCanonicalPath(): String {
        val androidDataSegment = "/Android/data/"

        val canonicalPath = canonicalPath

        if (canonicalPath.contains(androidDataSegment, true)) {
            val regex = Regex(androidDataSegment, RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
            return canonicalPath.replace(regex, androidDataSegment)
        }

        return canonicalPath
    }


However, I would like to know if anyone else has encountered a similar issue and if there is any explanation for this unusual behavior.
